# How to translate `Inclusive growth` into Russian?

Tags: перевод

[Inclusive growth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusive_growth) is an economic term, I tried to translate as `инклузивное развитие` or `включительное развитие`, but not sure because search engines give me very few results.

Comment: `I tried to translate as инклузивное развитие` Try инкл**ю**зивное развитие (or рост) instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Инклюзи́вный рост/разви́тие*.

I got these numbers of hits in Google:

- "инклюзивный рост" 4450
- "инклюзивное развитие" 3320
- "включающий рост" 643

"Инклюзивный рост" and "инклюзивное развитие" seem to refer to the term in question while "включающий рост" and "включающее развитие" are mostly combinations of the participle of "включать" followed by "рост/развитие".

A few usage examples:

- *"Сегодня экономисты на Западе пользуются понятием inclusive growth — включающий рост, дающий возможность наблюдать, как изменяется экономическое положение отдельных социальных групп или регионов страны."* ([link](http://kommersant.ru/doc/3049213))
- *ИНКЛЮЗИВНЫЙ УСТОЙЧИВЫЙ РОСТ: ПРИОРИТЕТЫ, ИНДИКАТОРЫ, МЕЖДУНАРОДНЫЙ ОПЫТ, ПОТЕНЦИАЛ СОГЛАСОВАНИЯ С МОДЕЛЬЮ РЕИНДУСТРИАЛИЗАЦИИ* ([link](http://group-global.org/ru/publication/66990-inklyuzivnyy-ustoychivyy-rost-prioritety-indikatory-mezhdunarodnyy-opyt-potencial))
- *"Инклюзивное развитие" - главная тема Боаоского азиатского форума-2011* ([link](http://russian.cntv.cn/program/news_ru/20110414/103308.shtml))

Answer (score 2):

I think there is no consensus about translation yet and everybody try on their own. I have faced with `всеобъемлющий` (and have accepted this for me) it has 3 470 search results on google.

Answer (score 1):

Google scholar находит `инклюзивный рост` и `инклюзивное развитие` почти поровну (81 и 82 текста, соответственно)

"Включающий рост" находится в 19 текстах, но все или почти все тексты совершенно не о том. Пример:

> Для него характерен широкий спектр эруптивной активности, включающий
>   рост экструзивных куполов и их разрушение последующими взрывами разной
>   силы.

(Речь идёт о вулкане.)